HCMOS Oscillator output waveform measurement fault
My ASV-50.000MHZ-EJ-T oscillator's  datasheet is here .
My goal is to measure the oscillator output with an oscilloscope.
The ideal square waveform I expect is as follows,

my measurement setup  Hantek MPO6204d 200Mhz  probe 1x mode


The image I see on the oscilloscope is as follows.

Let's look at the output value according to the information given in the datasheet.
High state 0.9 x Vdd
0.9 x 3.3V=2.97V
Low state max 0.4V
Oscilloscope measurement max 2.1V
min 1.23V
I also see a triangular wave, not a square wave
What is the reason of this?
Here are the possibilities

I see the triangle waveform due to reflections (due to impedance equalization).

The gnd probe of the oscilloscope probe with which I made the  forms a huge loop.

I completely miss things.

Oscillator output is as it should be.



new test changes added 100nF beetwen input
changed 1x to 10 x mode






Another factor (not the single reason you're asking for) is the high supply impedance as you've got no decoupling. As a quick experiment, you can solder 100nF straight across the module pins (must be right there, close) and repeat your measurement.

What oscilloscope is that? What scope probe are you using, x1 or x10? If the bandwidth of the scope is lower than 200MHz you won't see a square wave.

Hantek MPO6204d 200Mhz  probe 1x mode

Many 'scopes have a 20 MHz bandwidth setting - is that selected? That would seriously attenuate and deform a 50 MHz signal.  (What does the "B" in the input setting boxes mean?)

You should use the probe 10x mode for high speed. The input capacitance of the probe is much lower when switched to 10x. Read the datasheet of the probe and the oscillator and compare the probe capacitance with the max. output load of 15 pF.  When you measure a 50 MHz signal with 200 MHz sample rate, you get only 4 samples per period. A 10 or 20 MHz oscillator would look much better with 20 or 10 samples per period

Yes, you were right, I did not pay attention to the features of my probe. 1x mode up to 5MHz, 10x mode up to 200Mhz, 18pF. Even this is too much for output measurement, it exceeds the max value.
and acts like a filter

The first problem is that you expect an ideal square wave - that can never happen in practice, as ideal square waves have infinitely fast slew rate that toggles between states in no time, so you need infinite bandwidth and energy for that. Your oscillator data sheet says rise and fall times are 2.2 to 4.0 nanoseconds.

Not really due to impedance mismatch and reflections - they may play a role, but there's far worse issues.

That is a problem, but only after the other problems are solved.

Yes, correct

Maybe, it is hard to prove but it is likely that no part of your wiring or probing allow for a 50 MHz square wave oscillator to work properly and be probed properly.


First problem is that you are using a 1x probe. Read the probe specs or data sheet - it will have a very low bandwith in 1x mode. Always use 1x/10x probes in 10x mode, unless you know what you are doing and have determined you are in a situation where using 1x mode is justified.
Also check the specs of the actual probe - you have only stated the specs of the scope to be 200 MHz, the probes are still unknown.
Second problem is the supply wiring. There is no bypass cap and the long random wiring is basically not a wire but inductances. The oscillator can't get power quick enough to do 50 MHz square wave, the wiring inductance prevents it.
Third problem is the probe connection. Wire inductance means that loop of wire can't measure 50 MHz square wave. You need to use the ground spring and connect the tip and spring right at the crystal.
Fourth problem is that a square wave has only odd harmonics. Base frequency is 50 MHz, next harmonic is third at 150MHz, and the next is fifth harmonic at 250 MHz so that and all the other higher harmonics that make up the square wave can't be measured any more by your scope.
So you can never see a 50 MHz square wave with that scope, no matter how good probes or probe connections or power connections or power bypassing you use.
